# "Device connection lost " error in android app

Tags: java, php, android, rest, sensors

I am finding "a device connection lost" error when i am getting values from external sensor and displaying in android app and web service. I can display some values but after some time the app is closing by giving message "device connection lost". If anybody can help me by letting me know whats the main reason to lost connection, will be really appreciable. 
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

1. Try different USB ports on your computer.
2. Check if the USB cord you are using is faulty.